# Detect stripe pattern in image?

Tags: image-processing

I'm looking for some ideas to find out the stripe pattern in the image. It can be vertical, horizontal or even diagonal. Every lines have a same shade of color (let's say the difference in hue is around 20 degree) and it can be any colors if it can be distinguished by human eyes. It will be fine if the result is in binary.

Here the example image.

[image: Example Image]

Here the expected output image.

[image: Result]

Comment: Is the distance between two consecutive stripes constant and known?
Is the stripe width constant and known?